# WSO2 AM deploy error java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable) on Centos7 Server

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm using AM 2.6.0. When I deploy in PC using Window everything OK. But when I deploy it on Centos7 Server it has error below. I try config as the following docs [https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP430/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjYVR.png) but still has this error. 
Please let me know if you have any other solutions in my case. Tks all! 
Sorry I'm newbie so cant show image in post. Error in this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjYVR.png